# Hibernate issue- CASCADE.ALL VS CASCADE.MERGE

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Why would it be when using Cascade all my project would break:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.Springboottutorial.entity.Child] with root cause
```

But when using Cascade MERGE it would fix the issue?

Anyone come across this issue?

```
 @JsonManagedReference("parent")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Child> childs;
```